Time complexity of this code which according to me is O(nlogn)
Can anyone please tell me the time complexity of the code
count = 0

for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        count++;

Please give me the time complexity. Because according to my calculation the outer loop is dividing n by 2 so it's running logn times and the inner loop is running n times so the time complexity is nlogn but according to the key for this question the time complexity is n.
Can anyone please clarify If I'm wrong please correct me where I'm wrong.
I tried all the ai tools and everything gave me nlogn

The inner loop goes from 0 to i, not to n

So the inner bit runs n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... times which is... (use math to continue)

I admit at first glance it seems like it's O(nlog(n)), but it isn't.  It's actually O(n).  The outer loop runs O(log(n)) times, but the inner loop runs a total of n + n/2 + n/4 + ... times (as mentioned in the previous comment), which is approximately 2n.  So it's O(n).  You can verify this by examining the value of count, which is the total number of times the inner loop runs.  It should be close to 2*n.

The time complexity in the real-world where computers exist is O(0). Because in the real world, this whole code will get replaced with something like count = 2*n and there will be no loops and no comparisons. So how did algorithm theory help us become better programmers here... or did it in fact do the opposite?

@Lundin in the real world we don't usually write sorting algorhithms either, but we still study them because the value is in learning to reason about stuff, not necessarily in the real world applications. Also, in the real world where real comptuers exist but without optimizations enabled that code does run approximately 2*n times.

@FedericoklezCulloca I write them occasionally, working with embedded systems where you take analog input and wish to filter it somehow. For example by applying a median filter. Calling qsort from inside an interrupt is a no-go, so you have to write it yourself. And well, you may have a point is case n is a value obtained at run-time, in which case compiler will not necessarily be able to untangle the non-trivial loops. But if n is a compile-time constant, I definitely expect the compiler to remove all of the loops.

@Lundin nitpicking - count = 2*n is O(1) (i.e. requires a constant number of operations), not O(0). The only function which is in O(0) is the constant 0 fucntion itself ;-)

@wohlstad there are many functions that are O(0) -- any function that is eventually always 0 is O(0). The only non-negative increasing function that is O(0) is 0.

@wohlstad Now that depends on what "O" is counting: the number of comparisons or the number of writes to the variable count. "Big O" is unhelpful like that.

@PaulHankin you are right about O(0), I stand corrected. However when analyzing algorithms non-negative increasing functions are the interesting ones.

@Lundin I actually meant to consider the number of operations in general (comparisons, writes or any other) in the big O. But anyway I agree it's not really relevant or interesting for analyzing this kind of procedures.

@wohlstad Ok but then the "O" becomes non-trivial since you have 1 initialization in the outer loop and n ones in the inner loop, then a number of comparisons, increments of iterators and increments of count. Suddenly we aren't talking about algorithm theory but real-world program performance! The computer scientists will be furious if they find out. Like, considering things such as division usually being a whole lot slower than plain increment/decrement... except if division by 2 which can get optimized into a bit shift.

Outer loop goes log2(n) times with i.
Inner loop goes from 0 to i, so you get
n/1 + n/2 + n/4 + ... + n/(2^k)
iterations, where k is the number of the outer iterations. This is same as
n * (1/(2^0) + 1/(2^1) + 1/(2^2) + ... + 1/(2^k))
and
n * (sum from k = 0 to log2(n) of 1/(2^k)).
This is n times a geometric series that goes towards 2, so overall you have n * 2 and, thus, O(n).

For non-negative n, count(n) = 2n - popcnt(n) (where popcnt(n) is the number of bits set in the binary representation of n).
Proof by induction:

the base cases of n=0 and n=1 are correct by inspection.
For larger n, we get count(n) = n + count(floor(n/2)).

If n was even, then count(n) = n + 2n/2 - popcnt(n)) = 2n - popcnt(n).
If n was odd, then count(n) = n + 2(n-1)/2 - (popcnt(n) - 1) = 2n - popcnt(n).



So we have that count gets incremented exactly 2n-popcnt(n) times. In complexity terms, popcnt(n) = O(log n), so this program is O(n).
